# php array is empty not work

Tags: php, arrays

I have a dynamically generated array. sometimes it's value is null, when it is null the browser gives an error.
therefore I want to check if the array is empty.
when  array is empty i use

```
echo var_dump($myarray);
```

then browser echoing following

i want to identify this kind of situation i use

```
  array(0) { }
```

i try flowing method but it didn't work

```
$errors = array_filter($myarray);
if( !empty($errors)){
       //do 
}
```

also i try

```
if ($myarray==''){
 //not working
}
```

Comment: `if ($array)` - that'll be true when the array is not empty and false when it is empty.

Comment: If your array is null then just check if it's null using the is_null function or with a exact comparison: `if(NULL === $myarray){ echo "NULL"; } else { echo "NOT NULL"; }`

Answer (score 0):

This will work for arrays and multidimensional arrays alike.

It also removes empty strings. such as `[0] => ""`

```
if (!array_filter($myarray) { 
    //If the array is empty
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$errors = array();

if(count($myarray)>0)
{
    $errors = array_filter($myarray);  
}

if(count($errors)>0)
{
    // do here !!
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to use `array_filter`. You can simply check for array being empty this way:

```
if(empty($myarray)){
    // Code to execute when array is empty.
}
else {
    // Code to execute when array is not empty.
}
```

Comment: Please don't use `empty` when there's no need for error suppression. Just use `if (!$myarray)` for the same effect while keeping PHP's error reporting mechanism working.

Comment: It is outside the scope of this question. Read what OP has asked carefully.

Comment: Using `empty` when it's not necessary is a bad practice. Please try to perpetuate *good* practices in any sample code you provide. My -1 is for perpetuating bad practices, as simple as that.

Comment: Believer of the Y Theory of motivation, I see. Thank you for the info. It was useful!